How to remove Google Chrome shortcut links from applications list?
At some point google chrome created shortcuts, which is just a link basically, in apps list. I guess when I've entered via my second profile, as all links opens with it. It sounds silly, but I really can't find how to remove them.
Applications screenshot:

I've found create shortcut option in chrome, but not remove one:
Chrome options screenshot:

Google Chrome v123.0.6312.86, Ubuntu 22.04
